# Edit suggestions ban threshold

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I got blocked from editing again.

I wanted to know from when (ratio approve/reject?) I get blocked. For example, in my last 10 suggested edits, 7 were approved and 3 were rejected. Is this the ratio?

I'm not angered against anyone here (unlike my previous post), I just want to know from which point I can get blocked. It's now been the third time since the creation of my account and, trust me, over 2 weeks of being blocked from editing and reviewing out of the ~80 days I've been on this site is *very* long.

Comment: You’d have a better experience if you focused on submitting  ***accurate and timely edits that improve a) the post and b) the site***.  Currently, you’re focused on the hard limits of various policies of the site and, as you’ve learned (hopefully) it’s not a recipe for success

Comment: @Allan Ah yeah, I think I learned that. The hard way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a system-wide feature and the specifics may not be public (for IMHO obvious reasons). You may find more about it on [Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=suggestion+edit-ban).

Comment: Okay, I might propose to reduce the ban period (7 days to 2 or 5) on Meta SE later.